# Using Google Analytics To Track Ad Calls

Tags: google-analytics

I'm using a 3rd party ad server for my site and the data for average ad calls/page within that ad server seems to be low for what I would expect. Is there a way to setup google analytics so that whenever I load an ad on my site I can also add to a value with the pageview (note that there may be multiple ads in a single page)? I was looking at using a custom metric for this, but how would I set that up if some pages might have 2 ads and others might have 3 and I want to verify that all 3 ad spots made the ad call before the user left for another page. So for example this way I can see that on a certain day I averaged 2 ad calls per page.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a Google display ad network then you probably have [a close to turnkey solution](http://marketingland.com/google-analytics-now-tracking-unclicked-display-video-ad-impressions-48995) at your disposal.

But presumably you're using something else, in which case you have a couple options.

The ideal solution probably involves tying the impression counts directly to your GA account by [importing cost data using the Management API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/data-import-cost). No tricky business. Straight impression counts from the source.

Otherwise you can [write some JS to detect ads](http://marketlytics.com/tracking-banner-impressions-using-google-tag-manager-and-universal-analytics/) and fire when they load.

Or else you can go [the transparent pixel route](http://www.statstory.com/tracking-clicks-and-impressions-in-google-analytics/).

You have options.